# cudaLaunch returns 0x9 in debugger

Tags: cuda

I have some pretty simple code to approximate a partial derivative on a uniform 3D grid. I'm running on scientific linux and when I compile with nvcc I get no errors or warnings. I check for a return of `cudaSuccess` for every `cudaMalloc()` and `cudaMemcpy()` call and indeed everything works just fine.

When I run my program without the debugger everything seems to work fine except that the kernel doesn't actually seem to execute. The array I allocate for my output (initialized to hold all zeros) still has all zeros after the kernel launch even if I do something silly like make each thread set an index of the array to 5.

So when I tried using cuda-gdb on this code it says `cudaLaunch()` returns 0x9. I'm not sure what error 9 is and couldn't find it quickly via a google search. So before I write out the code, which error is number 9? Is there a list of how the numbers match to the particular errors somewhere?

Is there a list online of how the error numbers map to specific errors?

I don't have the code on this machine, but it's something like:

```
dim3 dimGrid(1,1,1);
dim3 dimBlock(mx,my,mz);
x_derivative<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(f_d,df_d);
```

where (currently) `mx=my=mz=64`.

Perhaps the 64^3 number of threads is too large? Clearly that aren't that many actual threads on the GPU (it's a Tesla C2050 fwiw) but I thought I could just specify any number of threads? It's also noteworthy that this is a "naive" version of the algorithm, so I'm not looking to optimize performance (yet).

Comment: 0x9 is  cudaErrorInvalidConfiguration. How do you launch your kernel?

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the code on this machine, but it's something like:

Comment: If it's anything like that, no wonder it doesn't work. There is nothing there. ;) Just update your question to include the exact information.

Comment: @Bart Doh. Thanks for the help! Also, is there a document online that shows how the error numbers map to errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of threads per block is 512 or 1024 depending on your device. So yes, 64^3 is too big indeed.

Comment: OK. Makes sense, thanks again. Is there a similar limit on the number of blocks?

Comment: Appendix F of your CUDA C Programming Guide contains all the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, had you been checking error codes after the launch, you would have saved a lot of time. Since you don't have a sync after your launch, if you check the result of the kernel launch it will give you the result of just the kernel launch, and not the full kernel execution itself.